# Sending message on bot join not working discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot send a message whenever it joins a server.

This is my code so far:

```
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
  guild.systemChannel.send(`Hello, I'm LMAOBOT. Thanks for inviting me, here are a list of all my commands! :alien:`, {
    embed:{
        title: ':x: Prefix',
        color: 0x2471a3, 
        description: "The prefix for all my commands is \'lmao\', e.g: \'lmao help\'.",
        fields:[
            {
                name: ':tada: Fun',
                value: 'agree, dankrate, gayrate, 8ball, meme, pun, roll, coinflip, doge, kappa, lenny, lol, megusta, pepe, sanic, spiderman, spooderman, troll, wat, dolan, notsure, alone, pupper, kitty'
            },     
            {
                name: ':tools: Utilities',
                value: 'help, ping, invite'
            },
            {
                name: ':loud_sound: Sound Board - WARNING (EARRAPE)',
                value: 'reee, airhorn, momgetthecamera, 20thcenturyfox, dedotatedwam, friendzoned, gofuckyourself, gottagofast, illuminati, ohmygod, pussy, sadviolin, smokeweed, ohbabyatriple, wombocombo, wow'
            } 
        ],

        footer: {
            text: 'LMAOBot created and developed by Pete#4164.'
        }
    }
  });
});
```

My code is inconsistent as they removed the `.defaultChannel` command, I'm using `systemChannel`. But if the #general channel is removed it will output:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

in console.

So how will I make it so the bot sends to the first channel it has permissions to? Cause now it crashes whenever the #general isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the bot send to the first channel through this piece of code:

```js
let defaultChannel = "";
guild.channels.forEach((channel) => {
  if(channel.type == "text" && defaultChannel == "") {
    if(channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) {
      defaultChannel = channel;
    }
  }
})
//defaultChannel will be the channel object that it first finds the bot has permissions for
defaultChannel.send(`Hello, I'm LMAOBOT. Thanks for inviting me, here are a list of all my commands! :alien:`, {
embed:{
    title: ':x: Prefix',
    color: 0x2471a3, 
    description: "The prefix for all my commands is \'lmao\', e.g: \'lmao help\'.",
    fields:[
        {
            name: ':tada: Fun',
            value: 'agree, dankrate, gayrate, 8ball, meme, pun, roll, coinflip, doge, kappa, lenny, lol, megusta, pepe, sanic, spiderman, spooderman, troll, wat, dolan, notsure, alone, pupper, kitty'
        },     
        {
            name: ':tools: Utilities',
            value: 'help, ping, invite'
        },
        {
            name: ':loud_sound: Sound Board - WARNING (EARRAPE)',
            value: 'reee, airhorn, momgetthecamera, 20thcenturyfox, dedotatedwam, friendzoned, gofuckyourself, gottagofast, illuminati, ohmygod, pussy, sadviolin, smokeweed, ohbabyatriple, wombocombo, wow'
        } 
    ],

    footer: {
        text: 'LMAOBot created and developed by Pete#4164.'
    }
}
```

});

edit: whoops I made a mistake! ):

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Raymond's answer, you'll need to use `guild.channels.cache.forEach()` instead of `guild.channels.forEach`